# Cocos2D + Box2D Editor?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to develop an Angry Birds style game (more for learning purpose), so I am digging into Cocos2D + Box2D and after having done a few test all by code I am wondering which tool can I use to design level easier ?

A bit of google pointed me out Tiled or R.U.B.E. but I am not really sure if it's what I need. Tiled seem to be more designed for tiled game like a plat-former and I don't really know about R.U.B.E.

What I'd like to do is being able to place my body manually in a scene, set their physic property and so...

Which tool would you recommend for this kind of level design ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to download/buy [**LevelHelper/SpriteHelper**](http://www.gamedevhelper.com/), they have helped me a lot when I was a novice with box2d.  I think it's just what you need, once you learn the basics then you can go forward freely without them. In addition now there's also one or more tutorials on the Ray Wenderlich site that will help you even more [**like this**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28713/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-latest-levelhelper-spritehelper-cocos2d-edition-part-1) (The softwares are not free, but in my opinion  they worth their price)